# is there multiple header in sap.m.Table like sap.ui.table.Table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sapui5

```
    var otable = new sap.m.Table();//here table is created
//here multiple header I'm trying to create this can happen in sap.ui.table.Table but I want some thin in sap.m.Table
        var oColumns = new sap.m.Column({
        multiLabels: [
        new sap.m.Label({//here is main header
        text: "Input",
        textAlign: "Center"
        }),//here is sub header as input one
        new Button({
        text: "Input1"                          
        })
    ]
});
```

//is there some idea to create multi Level Header column in sap.m.Table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sap.m.Column does not support a list of Controls, however you can add a layout Control as header to include multiple Controls in the header:

```js
var oTable = new sap.m.Table({
    columns: [
        new sap.m.Column({
            header: new sap.m.VBox({
                new sap.m.Label({
                    text: "Input",
                    textAlign: sap.ui.core.TextAlign.Center
                }),
                new Button({
                    text: "Input1"
                })
            })
        })
    ]
});
```