# Multiple headers in sap.m table

Tags: sapui5

Please help me in how to set multiple headers and headerSpan in sap.m.table

I have to create a table using sap.m library only and my table should like below image

[image: 1]

I tried using vboxes in column->header->vbox

But unable to group columns and i need underline

Comment: Does this answer your question? [is there multiple header in sap.m.Table like sap.ui.table.Table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35986369/is-there-multiple-header-in-sap-m-table-like-sap-ui-table-table)

Comment: This question already has an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35986369/is-there-multiple-header-in-sap-m-table-like-sap-ui-table-table